# Using both setActionExpression() and setUrl() on MenuItem object is not working?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Hello I'm generating Primefaces menu from ManagedBean using default Menu Model.
Here is my Code.

menu.xhtml

```
<h:form>
 <p:menu model="#{menuProvider.menuModel}"/>
</h:form>
```

MenuProvider.java

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class MenuProvider {

    MenuModel menuModel;
    MenuItem menuPage1,menuPage2,menuPage3,menuPage4;

    public MenuProvider() {

        menuModel = new DefaultMenuModel();

        ExpressionFactory factory = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().getExpressionFactory();
        MethodExpression methodExpression = factory.createMethodExpression(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getELContext(), "#{menuProvider.myAction('page1')}", Void.class, new Class[]{String.class});

        menuPage1 = new MenuItem();
        menuPage1.setValue("Page 1");
        menuPage1.setId("page1");
            menuPage1.setActionExpression(methodExpression);
        menuPage1.setUrl("/pages/page1.xhtml");//If i Remove this line then Action listener will work


        menuModel.addMenuItem(menuPage1);

        System.out.println("MenuModel() called");;
    }

    public MenuModel getMenuModel() {
        return menuModel;
    }

    public void setMenuModel(MenuModel menuModel) {
        this.menuModel = menuModel;
    }


    public void myAction(String ae)
    {
        System.out.println("Listener---");
        System.out.println(ae);
    }

}
```

My Problem is On Menu Item object from above code only one will,
If I remove setUrl() method the setActionExpression() will work.
If I keep serUrl() method the setActionExpression() will NOT work.
Is there any specific reason for that? or Am I missing something.?

**EDIT** I'm using Primefaces 3.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usage of [`<p:menuitem>`](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/3.5/primefaces-p/menuitem.html) ([showcase example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/menu.jsf)) is twofold. Basically, both use cases are to my knowledge *mutually exclusive*, which is very well supported by logical analysis.

### `<p:menuitem>` acting as a plain get link

In this use case `<p:menuitem>` is basically acting as a plain navigational link, much with the flavour of `<h:link>` if `outcome` is specified, or `<h:outputLink>` if `url` is specified. You can't attach listeners to that kind of links. The basically generate plain `a` element with a specified `href`.

You would like to use it *within such context* for navigational purposes, to create a menu for navigation. To recite the showcase example:

```
<p:menu>  
    <p:submenu label="Navigations">  
        <p:menuitem value="External" url="http://www.primefaces.org" icon="ui-icon-home"/>  
        <p:menuitem value="Internal" outcome="/mobile/index" icon="ui-icon-star"/>  
    </p:submenu>  
</p:menu>
```

### `<p:menuitem>` acting as a means of performing business actions

In this use case `<p:menuitem>` is basically acting as a command component that submits a form and does business actions, much in the flavour of `<h:commandLink>`/`<h:commandButton>` with the appropriate `action` and `actionlistener` attributes. You can't attach your urls to the command links/buttons. They basically generate `a` element that posts the form via JavaScript with `href="#"` or an `input type="submit"`.

You would like to use it *within such context* for performing business actions and possibly posting some data with necessary navigation, if it is needed. To recite the showcase example:

```
<p:menu>  
    <p:submenu label="Ajax Menuitems">  
        <p:menuitem value="Save" actionListener="#{menuBean.save}" update="messages" icon="ui-icon-disk" />  
        <p:menuitem value="Update" actionListener="#{menuBean.update}" update="messages" icon="ui-icon-arrowrefresh-1-w"/>  
    </p:submenu>  
    <p:submenu label="Non-Ajax Menuitem">  
        <p:menuitem value="Delete" actionListener="#{menuBean.delete}" update="messages" ajax="false" icon="ui-icon-close"/>  
    </p:submenu>  
</p:menu>
```

---

It is somehow confusing when you're first time at it. But when you try to understand that sort of things deeper you'll easily get a grasp of the logics behind and will use `<p:menuitem>` component accordingly.

Comment: Thanks skuntsel. I understand that.